# Rake db:migrate rails with error undefined method `session_store_host`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have several databases across various geolocations. Each has its own representation in my database.yml file.

When running `RAILS_ENV=europe rake db:migrate` I am getting the following error

`` undefined method `session_store_host' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000038fdda8> ``

Stack:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
/var/www/vhosts/adm.dyqa.io/html/releases/20190324134144/config/initializers/session_store.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
```

My database file:

```
europe:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: production
  pool: 10
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
  host: database.mycompany.europe
  port: 1234

danger:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: production
  pool: 10
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
  host: database.mycompany.usa
  port: 1234
```

Comment: can you please share content of  `/config/environments/europe.rb`?

Comment: That was my problem, I was missing the environment config file!  Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the config file `europe.rb`
After creating that, the migration ran successfully.